# Python - iterate text file and create dictionary of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have text file with 3 space separated columns. I am trying to find for column A how many Column B have Passed. Value in Column B is considered Pass if there are no Status other than Pass in Column C for a value in Column B. So in example data below PRO-16 is considered Fail while PRO-18 is Pass and so on. 
Code wise I tried to convert this in a dict and iterate over inner dict to find if Column C has any status other passed for a Column B but no luck.
thanks a lot for your help!!

Edit: this is the code I am using to build a dict but it only reads first line of text file:
myFile = pd.read_csv('SIT Req.txt')

```
dataDict={}
for line in myFile:
        words = line.strip().split()
        fa = words[0]
        req = words[1]
        state = words[2]
        innerDict = dataDict.setdefault(fa, {})
        innerDict[req] = state

FT  PRO-16  Passed
FT  PRO-16  Failed
FT  PRO-18  Passed
FT  PRO-18  Passed
FT  PRO-19  Passed
FT  PRO-20  Failed
FT  PRO-21  No Run
FT  GR-01   Passed
FT  GR-02   Passed
FT  GR-02   Passed
FT  GR-02   Passed
FT  GR-03   Passed
LE  GR-19   Passed
LE  GR-19   Passed
LE  GR-20   Passed
LE  GR-21   Failed
LE  GR-22   Passed
LE  DEL-14  Passed
LE  DEL-14  Passed
LE  DEL-14  Passed
LE  DEL-15  Failed
LE  PRO-43  Failed
LE  PRO-45  Passed
LE  PRO-51  Passed
CD  GR-07   Passed
CD  GR-07   Failed
CD  GR-09   Passed
CD  GR-07   Passed
CD  GR-07   Passed
CD  GR-13   No Run
CD  GR-13   No Run
CD  GR-13   No Run
CD  GR-13   Failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to create a dictionary with column A as keys and each with a `defaultdict(list)` for the value. The nested `defaultdict(list)` uses column B as keys and a list of the values from column C.

The following code creates such a dictionary and then uses it to produce the counts of passed column B items for each column A.

```
from pandas import read_csv
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(list))

df = read_csv('datafile', sep='\t')
for a, b, c in df.values:
    data[a][b].append(c)

#from pprint import pprint
#pprint(data.items())

# output the total number of passes for each "A" in which all runs of "B" passed.
result_counts = {a: sum(1 for b in data[a] if all(c=='Passed' for c in data[a][b])) for a in data}
print('Counts: {}'.format(result_counts))

# output for each "A" a list of all passed "B"s.
result_passed = {a: list(b for b in data[a] if all(c=='Passed' for c in data[a][b])) for a in data}
print('Passed: {}'.format(result_passed))
```

**Output**

```
Counts: {'LE': 6, 'FT': 5, 'CD': 1}
Passed: {'LE': ['DEL-14', 'PRO-45', 'PRO-51', 'GR-19', 'GR-22', 'GR-20'], 'FT': ['PRO-19', 'PRO-18', 'GR-01', 'GR-03', 'GR-02'], 'CD': ['GR-09']}
```

**Update**

Regarding the trouble that you are having when iterating over the data frame, there are two problems that I see. Firstly the default field separator for `read_csv` is a comma. Your data appears to be tab separated. Secondly, your can't iterate directly over a data frame. Try using one of the following (I offer a few as they have different performance characteristics):

```
df = pd.read_csv('SIT Req.tx', sep='\t')    # note use of sep

for a, b, c in df.values:
    ...
# or
for i, a, b, c in df.itertuples():
    ...
# or
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    a, b, c = row
    ...
```

**Update 2**

Here is the long version of the dictionary comprehension that selects those items from column B for which all tests passed:

```
result_passed = {}
for a in data:
    result_passed[a] = []
    for b in data[a]:
        passed = True
        for c in data[a][b]:
            if c != 'Passed':
                passed = False
                break
        if passed:
            result_passed[a].append(b)
```

You can get a better understanding of how this works by looking at the content and structure of the `data` dictionary:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(data.items())
[('LE',
  defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'DEL-15': ['Failed'], 'DEL-14': ['Passed', 'Passed', 'Passed'], 'PRO-43': ['Failed'], 'PRO-45': ['Passed'], 'PRO-51': ['Passed'], 'GR-19': ['Passed', 'Passed'], 'GR-22': ['Passed'], 'GR-21': ['Failed'], 'GR-20': ['Passed']})),
 ('FT',
  defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'PRO-19': ['Passed'], 'PRO-20': ['Failed'], 'PRO-21': ['No Run'], 'PRO-16': ['Failed'], 'PRO-18': ['Passed', 'Passed'], 'GR-01': ['Passed'], 'GR-03': ['Passed'], 'GR-02': ['Passed', 'Passed', 'Passed']})),
 ('CD',
  defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'GR-07': ['Passed', 'Failed', 'Passed', 'Passed'], 'GR-09': ['Passed'], 'GR-13': ['No Run', 'No Run', 'No Run', 'Failed']}))]
```

Comment: In the output you showed PRO-16 is shown as pass while it should be failed as it has a corresponding Failed value as well in column C

Comment: @user5253936 : sorry, I didn't realise those requirements. I have updated my answer - I think it now addresses those requirements.

Comment: @user5253936 : also updated to show how to iterate over the pandas dataframe  returned by `read_csv()`.

Comment: - thank you so so very much! I feel so privileged to be around such smart people who care about the lesser intelligent population :D............thanks again

Comment: @user5253936 : you're welcome, it was an interesting problem to me, and I think that you should replace "intelligent" with "experienced".

Comment: I am trying to convert your 1 line solution into a more tree like structure for better understanding. Can u please recommend how to best interpret this line result_passed = {a: list(b for b in data[a] if all(c=='Passed' for c in data[a][b])) for a in data} . This is what I was trying :                                                                             for a in data:
    for b in data[a]:
        for c in data[a][b]:
            if all(c=='Passed' for c in data[a][b]):
                result_passed.setdefault(a,[]).append(b)

Comment: @user5253936 : see updated answer. The one-liner is a dictionary comprehension that lets you succinctly build dictionaries. Basically it is looking at each item from B and checking that all of the items from C passed. If they all passed, B is added to a list which is the values for item A.

Answer (score 0):

You can use defaultdict for this :

```
 from collections import defaultdict
 d = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(lambda : True))
 for line in f:
    words = line.split()
    if words[2]!='Passed':
       d[words[0]][words[1]] = False

In [49]: d['FT']['PRO-18']
Out[49]: True

In [50]: d['FT']['PRO-16']
Out[50]: False
```

Comment: his will give me all the Column Bs which have a Passed in Column C. Although as per my data set Column B can have multiple assoccited values in Column C. And Column B will only be considered passed if all associated values are passed. For eg in the dataset below PRO-16 is failed while PRO 18 is passed FT  PRO-16  Passed
FT  PRO-16  Failed
FT  PRO-18  Passed
FT  PRO-18  Passed
FT  PRO-19  Passed
FT  PRO-20  Failed
FT  PRO-21  No Run
FT  GR-01   Passed

Comment: @user5253936 what about this? If there was "not passed" field in C it will be false, otherwise - True

Comment: Interesting solution. Instead of making True or False can I add this to a list. The challenge is this is going to be a very large file and I may not be able to check for each individually. So my output may be : [FT: [PRO-18, X, Y]], [LE: [A, B , C]] -----> where A, B, C are passed values for LE from column B

Answer (score 0):

From the data you have, the items for column B all appear to be in the range of a column A entry, i.e column A appears to be contiguous. If this is the case, and as you are dealing with a large file, the following approach might be possible:

```
import csv, itertools

with open('input.csv', 'r') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=" ", skipinitialspace=True)

    for k1, g1 in itertools.groupby(csv_input, key=lambda x: x[0]):
        group = sorted(g1, key=lambda x: x[1])
        for k2, g2 in itertools.groupby(group, key=lambda x: x[1]):
            if all((cols[2] == 'Passed' for cols in g2)):
                print "%s %s Passed" % (k1, k2)
            else:
                print "%s %s Failed" % (k1, k2)
```

For the data you have given, the following results are displayed:

```
FT GR-01 Passed
FT GR-02 Passed
FT GR-03 Passed
FT PRO-16 Failed
FT PRO-18 Passed
FT PRO-19 Passed
FT PRO-20 Failed
FT PRO-21 Failed
LE DEL-14 Passed
LE DEL-15 Failed
LE GR-19 Passed
LE GR-20 Passed
LE GR-21 Failed
LE GR-22 Passed
LE PRO-43 Failed
LE PRO-45 Passed
LE PRO-51 Passed
CD GR-07 Failed
CD GR-09 Passed
CD GR-13 Failed
```